# image base64, and optimase output

Tags: c#, base64

I wanna send image through UDP, so I'm looking for the best compressed algorithm to do that in C#!
for my current way is to converting image to text file by using base64, then I optimize the output of base64 by compressing the file with gzip.

**Samples:**

Image1 => 75.6 KB

base64 Image1 => 100 KB

gzip Image1 => 74.9 KB

---

Image2 => 384 KB

base64 Image2 => 512 KB

gzip Image2 => 386 KB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try compressing the image first then do base64.
Depending on the image, GZip can be really efficient on the images themselves.
You might want to try to compress the Base64 after

Comment: Image compression is far more efficient than image to string and then string compression

Comment: than witch algorithm is best one for image ?